# Vertical overflow dynamic height between two fixed divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I have this highly enveloped layout (not my decision) which contains a table, which needs to be scrollable in any direction if needed. Setting a height would be less of a problem if siblings and parents would not be of a fixed, absolute, and relative positions.

The issue is that as soon as the `.controls` div gets expanded in height (when the viewport gets resized to a smaller size), a part of the scrollbar gets covered by `.footer` and cannot be clicked. If there is a horizontal scrollbar there, it also gets covered completely.

```
.filter-table {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 30px); // hmm!
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(25,125,100,0.1);
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;    
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zv2cdv9z/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments to the footer styling, by changing the position from fixed to absolute and made the bottom: -10px.  This lets the user scroll up or down so the footer doesn't permanently block anything, as follows:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #fff;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/dfLfvha1/1/